# Javascript inside PHP - Quote problems

Tags: php, javascript

I need to include some javascript in my php file but im having difficulty with the quotes inside the javascript

**This is the javascript:**

```
<scripttype="text/javascript">

    var sc_project = $$$$;

    var sc_invisible = $;

    var sc_security = "$$$$$$$";

    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://www.")

    document.write("<sc" + "ript type='text/javascript' src='" + scJsHost + "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></" + "script>");

</script>
```

**I tried**

```
echo {
    '<scripttype="text/javascript">

                var sc_project = $$$$$$;

                var sc_invisible = $;

                var sc_security = "$$$$$$";

                var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://www.")

                document.write("<sc" + "ript' . 'type=\'text/javascript\' src='' . ' + scJsHost + "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'.'></" + "script>");

            </script>';
        }
```

Any way to have this appear on my php page?

Comment: Why are you echoing it ? Why not close the php tag (?>) paste the code and open a new <php tag ?

Comment: `<scripttype="text/javascript">` is that a typo in your example?

Comment: I saw `document.write` and I skipped to comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script tag should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Because `type` is an attribute.

When you are using quotes in PHP, you can mix quotes for simple things...

```
$test = '<p id="example">Example using mixed quotes</p>';
```

And you can escape quotes if it gets more complicated...

```
$test = '<p id="example">Example using \'escaped\' quotes</p>';
```

So you could use this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    var sc_project = $$$$;

    var sc_invisible = $;

    var sc_security = "$$$$$$$";

    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://www.")

    document.write("<sc" + "ript type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'" + scJsHost + "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js\'></" + "script>");

</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing... can't you just close your PHP and then repoen it?

If not, try escaping the quotes. I generally like to wrap everything in double quotes, so I can put my variables inline without concatenation.

Also why are you using `.` concatentation in the javascript. I don't see any php there to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

It's php, you don't need echo. Just use

```
...
?>
<script>
  var sc_project = $$$$$$;
  ...
</script>
<?php
...
```

Since your script is outputting the page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$js = <<<'JS'
<scripttype="text/javascript">

    var sc_project = $$$$;

    var sc_invisible = $;

    var sc_security = "$$$$$$$";

    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://www.")

    document.write("<sc" + "ript type='text/javascript' src='" + scJsHost + "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></" + "script>");

</script>
JS;

echo $js;
```